# SVD++ vectorization with numpy or tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, vectorization, svd

I want to implement SVD++ with numpy or tensorflow. 
( https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8451/c2812a1476d3e13f2a509139322cc0adb1a2.pdf ) 
(4p equation 4)

[image]
I want to implement above equation without any for loop. 
But summation of y_j with index set R(u) makes it hard.

**So my question is... 
 
I want to implement below equation (q_v multiply sum of y_j) without any for loop 

1. Is it possible to implement it with numpy without for loop?! 

2. Is it possible to implement it with tensorflow without for loop?!**

[image]

**My implementation is below... but I want to remove for loop further more**

```
import numpy as np

num_users = 3
num_items = 5
latent_dim = 2
p = 0.1

r = np.random.binomial(1, 1 - p,(num_users, num_items))
r_hat = np.zeros([num_users,num_items])

q = np.random.randn(latent_dim,num_items)
y = np.random.randn(latent_dim,num_items)


## First Try
for user in range(num_users):
    for item in range(num_items):
        q_j = q[:,item]

        user_item_list = [i for i, e in enumerate(r[user,:]) if e != 0] # R_u

        sum_y_j = 0 # to make sum of y_i
        for user_item in user_item_list:
            sum_y_j = sum_y_j + y[:,user_item]
        sum_y_j = np.asarray(sum_y_j)

        r_hat[user,item] = np.dot(np.transpose(q_j),sum_y_j)
print r_hat

print "=" * 100

## Second Try
for user in range(num_users):
    for item in range(num_items):
        q_j = q[:,item]
        user_item_list = [i for i, e in enumerate(r[user,:]) if e != 0] # R_u
        sum_y_j = np.sum(y[:,user_item_list],axis=1) # to make sum of y_i
        r_hat[user,item] = np.dot(np.transpose(q_j),sum_y_j)
print r_hat

print "=" * 100

## Third Try
for user in range(num_users):
    user_item_list = [i for i, e in enumerate(r[user,:]) if e != 0] # R_u
    sum_y_j = np.sum(y[:,user_item_list],axis=1) # to make sum of y_i
    r_hat[user,:] = np.dot(np.transpose(q),sum_y_j)
print r_hat
```

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
sum_y = []
for user in range(num_users):
    mask = np.repeat(r[user,:][None,:],latent_dim, axis=0)
    sum_y.append(np.sum(np.multiply(y, mask),axis=1))
sum_y = np.asarray(sum_y)

r_hat = (np.dot(q.T,sum_y.T)).T
print r_hat
```

It eliminates the enumerate loop, and also the dot product can be done in single go. I don't think it can be reduced beyond this.

Comment: I agree with you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use two matrix-multiplications there with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for the final output -

```
r_hat = r.dot(y.T).dot(q)
```

Sample run to verify results -

OP's sample setup :

```
In [68]: import numpy as np
    ...: 
    ...: num_users = 3
    ...: num_items = 5
    ...: latent_dim = 2
    ...: p = 0.1
    ...: 
    ...: r = np.random.binomial(1, 1 - p,(num_users, num_items))
    ...: r_hat = np.zeros([num_users,num_items])
    ...: 
    ...: q = np.random.randn(latent_dim,num_items)
    ...: y = np.random.randn(latent_dim,num_items)
    ...: 

In [69]: ## Second Try from OP
    ...: for user in range(num_users):
    ...:     for item in range(num_items):
    ...:         q_j = q[:,item]
    ...:         user_item_list = [i for i, e in enumerate(r[user,:]) if e != 0] # R_u
    ...:         sum_y_j = np.sum(y[:,user_item_list],axis=1) # to make sum of y_i
    ...:         r_hat[user,item] = np.dot(np.transpose(q_j),sum_y_j)
    ...:
```

Let's print out the result from OP's solution -

```
In [70]: r_hat
Out[70]: 
array([[  4.06866107e+00,   2.91099460e+00,  -6.50447668e+00,
          7.44275731e-03,  -2.14857566e+00],
       [  4.06866107e+00,   2.91099460e+00,  -6.50447668e+00,
          7.44275731e-03,  -2.14857566e+00],
       [  5.57369599e+00,   3.76169533e+00,  -8.47503476e+00,
          1.48615948e-01,  -2.82792374e+00]])
```

Now, I am using my proposed solution -

```
In [71]: r.dot(y.T).dot(q)
Out[71]: 
array([[  4.06866107e+00,   2.91099460e+00,  -6.50447668e+00,
          7.44275731e-03,  -2.14857566e+00],
       [  4.06866107e+00,   2.91099460e+00,  -6.50447668e+00,
          7.44275731e-03,  -2.14857566e+00],
       [  5.57369599e+00,   3.76169533e+00,  -8.47503476e+00,
          1.48615948e-01,  -2.82792374e+00]])
```

Value check seems successful!

Comment: Totally different with the above equation which I wrote. It is not a just matrix multiplication

Comment: @user3704652 Then, is your **Second Try** wrong? Because I did a value check and seems to be matching. So, what am I missing here?